# Is query with EF in webforms different compared to mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is query with EF in webforms different compared to mvc? I am looking at tutorial for both mvc and webforms. Querying looks different to me. An clarification on this topic would be appreciated.  For example, in webforms you would use the using statement before you create the dbcontext or objectcontext. I have not seen the same approach being followed in mvc.

Comment: Please provide links to the information you are reading on the Internet that says this.

Comment: @Robert check the [Creating an Entity Framework Data Model for an ASP.NET MVC Application tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application): `private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();`, and "dispose" is not present on that page... @OP: nonetheless, you most likely always want to dispose objects implementing the `IDisposable` interface, you can assume the tutorials leave it out for simplicity.

Comment: See http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference.

The `using` statement is used because it automatically takes care of disposing the context for you. That means you don't need to worry about calling  `Dispose()` method on your `dbcontext`. You can use using statement in both `webforms` and `MVC`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is determining when the data is requested. If you surround your context with a using block but don't iterate over the result (ex. using ToList), you could just return the query definition to the form after your method runs, it could try to do the bind, but if the context is already disposed it won't return any results. The same issue could apply for MVC and WebForms depending on how you are binding your UI to the data which could be different based on your implementation. As with most cases, it depends.